# Add sum values to separate facets of stacked geom_col?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm trying to show the values of each bar on the plot, so that there are twelve unique values in total across the plot, by or on each bar. Each bar is made up of several stacked variables, and I've made an additional data frame with the sum totals of each bar. But instead they duplicate, when using geom_text. Is there any way to fix this? I've never posted here before, so I don't know how much I should provide of my code (it is extremely messy because I've Frankensteined the code from too many google searches)

The following, Finx, is the basis for my plot.

Finx:

```
  AROID         Marktäcke    Nutrient Area.km2 Konc.KgM3 Markan. 
   <chr>         <chr>        <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>   
 1 646432-143677 ExtensivVall N          5.36       952.  Jordbruk
 2 645785-143513 ExtensivVall N          5.86      1040.  Jordbruk
 3 645157-143904 ExtensivVall N          3.09       549.  Jordbruk
 4 646432-143677 Grönträda    N          2.87      3523.  Jordbruk
 5 645785-143513 Grönträda    N          0.956     1174.  Jordbruk
 6 645157-143904 Grönträda    N          0.100      123.  Jordbruk
 7 646432-143677 Havre        N          1.07      1712.  Jordbruk
 8 645785-143513 Havre        N          0.203      325.  Jordbruk
 9 645157-143904 Havre        N          0.0173      27.7 Jordbruk
10 646432-143677 Höstraps     N          1.16      2146.  Jordbruk
# … with 69 more rows
```

Which I work with to present the data.

```
Finx1 <- Finx %>%
  group_by(AROID, Nutrient) %>%
   mutate(AROID = recode(AROID, "645157-143904" = "Dis. Utl. Bonderydssjön", "646432-143677" = "Inloppet Tåkern", "645785-143513" = "Nära S:t Åby" )) %>%
     ungroup()

Fa <- Finx1 %>%
  group_by(AROID, Nutrient, Markan.) %>%
  summarize(Konc.KgM3) %>%
  summarize_all(sum) %>%
  mutate(Tot.kg = Konc.KgM3) %>%
  select(-Konc.KgM3)

Fum <- left_join(Finx1, Fa, by = c("AROID", "Nutrient"))
Fum <- Fum[!duplicated(Fum[c('Tot.kg')]), ]             
Fum[,'Tot.kg']=round(Fum[,'Tot.kg'], 0)
Fum <- Fum %>%
  select(-Markan..x)
```

Then I make the ggplot,

```
ggplot(Finx1) +
  aes(x = AROID, fill = Marktäcke, y = Konc.KgM3) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.8) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = wes_palette("Darjeeling1", type = "continuous", n = 17)) +
  theme_light() +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(aes(AROID, Tot.kg, label = Tot.kg, fill = NULL), size = 3, data = Fum2, hjust = 1) +
  facet_grid(Markan. ~ Nutrient, scales = "free_x") +
  ylab("Total mängd i Kg/år") +
  xlab("Delavrinningsområde") +
  labs(title='Utlakning av näringsämnen 2007') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, color = "#5A5A5A"), axis.title.x = element_text(color = "#383838"), axis.title.y = element_text(color = "#383838"))
```

[image]

I probably make some mistake here, like showing too little data or something. Idk, but I have no idea what I'm supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

In principle your ggplot2 code was fine but you messed up the data wrangling, which could be simplifeid without the need of a join:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(wesanderson)

Finx1 <- Finx %>%
  mutate(AROID = recode(AROID,
    "645157-143904" = "Dis. Utl. Bonderydssjön",
    "646432-143677" = "Inloppet Tåkern",
    "645785-143513" = "Nära S:t Åby"
  ))

Fum <- Finx1 %>%
  group_by(AROID, Nutrient, Markan.) %>%
  summarize(Tot.kg = sum(Konc.KgM3))

ggplot(Finx1) +
  aes(x = Konc.KgM3, y = AROID) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Marktäcke), alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_text(aes(x = Tot.kg, label = Tot.kg), size = 3, data = Fum, hjust = -.1) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0, 0, 1500)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = wes_palette("Darjeeling1",
    type = "continuous", n = 17
  )) +
  facet_grid(Markan. ~ Nutrient, scales = "free_x") +
  theme_light() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, color = "#5A5A5A"),
    axis.title = element_text(color = "#383838")
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "Total mängd i Kg/år",
    y = "Delavrinningsområde",
    title = "Utlakning av näringsämnen 2007"
  )
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
Finx <- structure(list(AROID = c(
  "646432-143677", "645785-143513", "645157-143904",
  "646432-143677", "645785-143513", "645157-143904", "646432-143677",
  "645785-143513", "645157-143904", "646432-143677"
), Marktäcke = c(
  "ExtensivVall",
  "ExtensivVall", "ExtensivVall", "Grönträda", "Grönträda",
  "Grönträda", "Havre", "Havre", "Havre", "Höstraps"
), Nutrient = c(
  "N",
  "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N"
), Area.km2 = c(
  5.36,
  5.86, 3.09, 2.87, 0.956, 0.1, 1.07, 0.203, 0.0173, 1.16
), Konc.KgM3 = c(
  952,
  1040, 549, 3523, 1174, 123, 1712, 325, 27.7, 2146
), Markan. = c(
  "Jordbruk",
  "Jordbruk", "Jordbruk", "Jordbruk", "Jordbruk", "Jordbruk", "Jordbruk",
  "Jordbruk", "Jordbruk", "Jordbruk"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  "1",
  "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"
))
```

Comment: Thanks! In the end I divided the plot into two separate plots for agricultural and non-agricultural instead, to avoid the duplicated sum values.